# Responsive Menu do not scroll to the right div, instead scrolls to top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been looking for an answer to my problems for hours now without finding anything combining every characteristic.

So, I have been trying to put in place a simple responsive navigation bar that scrolls to a specific div using javascript.

This nav bar works fine when I am at the top of the page. The problem is when I click on my links from any other position on the page, it straight jumps to the top and doesn't scroll to my specific div!

I don't know if it has to do with the JS function I use to scroll to my divs, to the way I have formatted my nav bar or to my poor knowledge of HTML structures. SO here down is everything I have.

Please note this: I have written my JS functions directly inside the html file so it makes everything a bit messy.

I really hope someone here will be able to help

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.toggle-nav').click(function(e) {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
    jQuery('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
$(".current-item").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".menu").offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
$(".scrollfeat1").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".feature1scroll").offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
$(".scrollfeat2").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".feature2scroll").offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
$(".scrollfeat3").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".feature3scroll").offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
$(".scrollfeat4").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".feature4scroll").offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: Geneva;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
p {
  color: #757575;
  font-family: Geneva;
}
/*----- Toggle Button -----*/

.toggle-nav {
  display: none;
}
/*----- Menu -----*/

@media screen and (min-width: 860px) {
  .menu {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    background: white;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
.menu ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu li {
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.menu li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.menu a {
  color: black;
  transition: color linear 0.15s;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu a:hover,
.menu .current-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #46B1C9;
}
/*----- Responsive -----*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
  .wrap {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 970px) {
  .search-form input {
    width: 120px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .menu {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
  }
  .menu ul.active {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu ul {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 120%;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: white;
  }
  .menu ul:after {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 22px;
    content: '';
    transform: translate(0%, -100%);
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #303030;
  }
  .menu li {
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .menu a {
    display: block;
  }
  .toggle-nav {
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    background: white;
    color: #777;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: color linear 0.15s;
  }
  .toggle-nav:hover,
  .toggle-nav.active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #46B1C9;
  }
}
#homediv {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 250px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#mainpager {
  padding-top: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}
#homeimg {
  max-width: 200px;
}
.centergalleries {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 6%;
}
.divsfeature {
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
}
.alignindiv {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.textfeat {
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin-right: 8%;
}
.imagefeat {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  max-width: 90%;
  background-color: white;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/zlEKIw2.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.positionbtn {
  margin-top: 6%;
  margin-bottom: 6%;
  text-align: center;
}
.btnmenu {
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #757575;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 90%;
}
.btnmenu p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.btnmenu:active {
  transform: translate(0px, 2px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 2px);
}
.blue {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: #757575;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  transition: background-color linear 0.2s;
}
.blue:hover {
  border: #46B1C9;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: #46B1C9;
}
.blue:hover p {
  color: white;
}
.footlign {
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.divfooter {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5%;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
#logo123 {
  max-height: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#copyright {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title></title>
<link rel="icon" href="">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="active">
    <li class="current-item"><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="scrollfeat1">Feature 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="scrollfeat2">Feature 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="scrollfeat3">Feature 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="scrollfeat4">Feature 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="registerdemo">Get a demo</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <a class="toggle-nav" href="#">&#9776;</a>
</nav>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1 id="mainpager">title of my new company<br>hello world</h1>
    <div class="centergalleries">
      <div id="homediv">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/l1DSaeN.png" id="homeimg">
        <h4>Feature 1</h4>
        <p>We do that to do that and you got to love it.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="homediv">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/l1DSaeN.png" id="homeimg">
        <h4>Feature 1</h4>
        <p>We do that to do that and you got to love it.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="homediv">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/l1DSaeN.png" id="homeimg">
        <h4>Feature 1</h4>
        <p>We do that to do that and you got to love it.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="homediv">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/l1DSaeN.png" id="homeimg">
        <h4>Feature 1</h4>
        <p>We do that to do that and you got to love it.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="positionbtn">
      <button class="btnmenu blue">
        <p>Click to get a demo</p>
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="feature1scroll">
    <div class="divsfeature alignindiv">
      <div class="imagefeat">
      </div>
      <div class="textfeat">
        <h2>Feature 1</h2>
        <p>The history of Latin poetry can be understood as the adaptation of Greek models. The verse comedies of Plautus are considered the earliest surviving examples of Latin literature and are estimated to have been composed around 205-184 BC. The start
          of Latin literature is conventionally dated to the first performance of a play in verse by a Greek slave, Livius Andronicus, at Rome in 240 BC. Livius translated Greek New Comedy for Roman audiences, using meters that were basically those of
          Greek drama, modified to the needs of Latin. His successors Plautus and Terence further refined the borrowings from the Greek stage and the prosody of their verse is substantially the same as for classical Latin verse.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature2scroll">
    <div class="divsfeature alignindiv">
      <div class="textfeat">
        <h2>Feature 2</h2>
        <p>The history of Latin poetry can be understood as the adaptation of Greek models. The verse comedies of Plautus are considered the earliest surviving examples of Latin literature and are estimated to have been composed around 205-184 BC. The start
          of Latin literature is conventionally dated to the first performance of a play in verse by a Greek slave, Livius Andronicus, at Rome in 240 BC. Livius translated Greek New Comedy for Roman audiences, using meters that were basically those of
          Greek drama, modified to the needs of Latin. His successors Plautus and Terence further refined the borrowings from the Greek stage and the prosody of their verse is substantially the same as for classical Latin verse.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="imagefeat">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature3scroll">
    <div class="divsfeature alignindiv">
      <div class="imagefeat">
      </div>
      <div class="textfeat">
        <h2>Feature 3</h2>
        <p>The history of Latin poetry can be understood as the adaptation of Greek models. The verse comedies of Plautus are considered the earliest surviving examples of Latin literature and are estimated to have been composed around 205-184 BC. The start
          of Latin literature is conventionally dated to the first performance of a play in verse by a Greek slave, Livius Andronicus, at Rome in 240 BC. Livius translated Greek New Comedy for Roman audiences, using meters that were basically those of
          Greek drama, modified to the needs of Latin. His successors Plautus and Terence further refined the borrowings from the Greek stage and the prosody of their verse is substantially the same as for classical Latin verse.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature4scroll">
    <div class="divsfeature alignindiv">
      <div class="textfeat">
        <h2>Feature 4</h2>
        <p>The history of Latin poetry can be understood as the adaptation of Greek models. The verse comedies of Plautus are considered the earliest surviving examples of Latin literature and are estimated to have been composed around 205-184 BC. The start
          of Latin literature is conventionally dated to the first performance of a play in verse by a Greek slave, Livius Andronicus, at Rome in 240 BC. Livius translated Greek New Comedy for Roman audiences, using meters that were basically those of
          Greek drama, modified to the needs of Latin. His successors Plautus and Terence further refined the borrowings from the Greek stage and the prosody of their verse is substantially the same as for classical Latin verse.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="imagefeat">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footlign"></div>
</body>

<footer class="footerfoot">
  <div class="divfooter">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/zlEKIw2.jpg" id="logo123">
  </div>
  <div class="divfooter">
    <h4>Features</h4>
    <p>Feature 1</p>
    <p>Feature 2</p>
    <p>Feature 3</p>
    <p>Feature 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="divfooter">
    <h4>Other pages</h4>
    <p>Contact</p>
    <p>About us</p>
    <p>Get a demo</p>
  </div>
  <div id="copyright">
    <p>&copy; whatapage.ch 2016</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Also, here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLhresLa/)

Comment: give a js fiddle link

Comment: This code is a mess... please try to make a snippet out of it! And read some documentation about the general structure of an html document.

Comment: You really need to convert this into a jsfiddle before we can try to assist you with this. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ok here is the Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qLhresLa/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`overflow: auto` on `html` tag breaks animate and in first block of features duplicated id's its bad, id must be unique on page.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLhresLa/2/)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of code is that?
I've never seen someone write script tag between HTML tag randomly
maybe It is because It executed before document.ready

you can add your script in HTML file in the bottom like this

```
<html>
<body>
...
...
...
    <script>
    ...
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It causes your js code run after DOM load

Comment: Alright I changed the structure of it, but it doesn't change anything to how it works. if you want to have a sense of my problem play a bit with the menu here and you'll see what I am talking about [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLhresLa/)